# Locating Amqp in the dependency jars

Tags: spring-boot, amqp

I am migrating up to springBootVersion = '2.2.10.RELEASE' from 1.x,
and when I compile against it, I have spring-integration-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar,
But I cannot locate this.

```
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.amqp.Amqp;
```

Documentation says I don't need to declare the dsl package due to duplicate declarations.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

What you  don't to show  pom file here ?  But anyway
In Spring Boot 2.2.x include  Spring Integration 5.0 if your pom to have dependency.

org.springframework.integration
spring-integration-java-dsl
Delete it.

Documentation says  it  has been added to  the version 5.0. Put it in pom or any other spring-cloud-starter- Spring Cloud include spring-integration.

spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit

Check in link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-4.3-to-5.0-Migration-Guide

org.springframework.integration.dsl.amqp.Amqp;
Now located in
org.springframework.integration.amqp.dsl.Amqp;